# How to describe the closure of a sub-group functor of a group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, representable-functors

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a field $k$, assume it has all the good conditions one may need (smooth, affine, algebraic, you name it).
Let now $H:Aff/k\to Gp$ be a group functor and $i:H\to G$ be a transformation of group functors which is a monomorphism, that is for every $X\in Aff/k$ one has $i(X):H(X)\to G(X)$ is injective.

In general, $H$ will not be a closed subfunctor (not even representable), but one can define the closure of $H$ as the smaller subgroup $\bar{H}$ of $G$ containing $H$ (that is, such that $i:H\to G$ factors through $\bar{H}$).

> **Main Question**: is there a way to describe $\bar{H}$, as a functor, only using the functorial descriptions of $G$ and $H$? By this I mean, a way to write $\bar{H}(X)=\{g\in G(X)\mid \dotsc\}$, where the dots should be filled with properties involving only $G(Y)$ and $H(Y)$, with $Y\in Aff/k$ (or, even better, $Y\in Aff/X$) and the natural morphisms between them.

Is this something one can expect or is there some meta-reason for which this should not be possible? Is the property of being a group really needed or can one ask the same for any scheme (with good properties) and subfunctor of its functor of points?